# External monitor is blank if I boot with the monitor plugged in

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Ubuntu 12.04 has problem with Intel GM45 Chipset, featuring the the Mobile Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 4500MHD

---

I have a COMPAQ Presario CQ70 laptop with an Intel GM45 chipset that features the Mobile Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 4500MHD. I was using the second HDMI video port to drive both a projector or a second monitor. Everything was working fine under Ubuntu 8.04, 9.04, 10.04 and 11.04, however, when I upgraded to 12.04 the second monitor stopped working.

What I mean when I say stopped working is:

1. boot with monitor plugged in.

   - Blank screen!
   - Power off, unplug monitor and power on everything works.
   - Plug in monitor (only mode that works in Mirror mode) two monitors that look same.
   - Close laptop lid. screen goes blank only option for useful system 
      is power off and unplug monitor.
2. If I attempt to Adjust the monitor to maximum resolution that the monitor will handle and turn off mirror mode nothing can be moved onto that screen.

This all worked fine with earlier versions of Ubuntu, is there a notes about the changes to the graphics management system in 12.04, like there is for the resolver change?

Answer (score 0):

I see similar behavior working through a KVM (TK-409) from my Lenovo T420 laptop.

The KVM mouse and keyboard switch fine and the extended monitor switch on only for a few seconds and then goes blank. Display settings page then says I do not have extended monitor.

The external screen switches on for a few seconds every time I switch the KVM to my laptop and it shows my extended desktop and my mouse can go there, but a few seconds later it reconfigures itself automatically as if it then checked and somehow decided the screen is no longer present - this behavior is similar to what happens when I unplug a screen without using KVM.

Syslog shows `mtp-probe: bus 1, device N was not an MTP device` but I am not sure if that is related or not.